# Required output from regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input:

```
ODU4 (PT=21)/ODU3 (PT=20)/ODU2 (PT=20)/ODU1 (PT=20)/ODU0
```

I want to filter it by regular expression which will result in the following output:

```
"PT21/PT20/PT20/PT20"
```

I am not an expert at creating regular expressions and it looks a little bit tricky, so please help me on same.

I am able to extract `PT=21` and other `PT=XX` substrings using the following regular expression:

```
\(.*?\)
```

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using?

Comment: "filter it by regular expression" - Filtering is not done by regex. What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry Amit, i don't know about the regex flavor, but i am trying to get it by Expresso tool.

Comment: Thank you Maroun for your view on it.Ohh, so it is not possible to get the exact result by regular expression. But partially it will be done, then i have to replace & append it? I am using C# in which by coding i can achieve it, but reviewer is asking for regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture texts inside round brackets, and then join them.

In C#, you can do it like this:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))");
var vals = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
var res = string.Join("/", vals);
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG7gH1/2)

You may also try to obtain the result using a `Regex.Replace`:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(/?)[^()]*\(([^()]*)\)|/[^()/]*$");
var res = rx.Replace(str, "$1$2");
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG7gH1/3)

Comment: Thank you Stribizhev for your answer, actually i did in similar way, but as per review i am looking for regex if it is possible.

Comment: Do you mean with a regex replacement? [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/nG7gH1/3)?

Comment: Yes, like you have used in first line to get PT=21, will it be possible to have a regular expression which can do what i am expecting or it is not possible to get by a single regular expression?

Comment: I am not sure what you want: match discontinuous text? It is not possible. You need to capture separate chunks of text you need and then build the output you need. The first approach is the most logical. The second is a bit messy, but it is using a *single* regex. I do not think there is another way of achieving what you need since you need to get your output from non-consecutive parts of the input string.

Comment: Thank you stribizhev for your clarification & help on same. I have to do in that way only i.e. with replace which will have lesser code & near my requirement.